# Why does the following code produce an indentation error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, comments

```
def search():
    try:
        option=input("\n\nWhta do you want to search by ('A' for account type, 'B' for balance): ")
        if option.lower()=='a':
            option_2=input("\n\nWhat type of account do you want to view ('C' for current,'S' for savings): ")
            if option_2.upper()=="C":
                inFile=open("account.dat","rb")
                acc_det=pickle.load(inFile)
                for x in acc_det:
                    if x.rettype()=="C":
                            print("\n\n\tACCOUNT HOLDER LIST\n\n")
                            print(60*"=")
                            print("%-10s"%"A/C No.","%-20s"%"Name","%-10s"%"Type","%-6s"%"Balance")
                            print(60*"=","\n")
                            x.report()

    except EOFError:
        print("Enter Valid Statement")



"""*****************************************************************************
                        THE MAIN FUNCTION OF PROGRAM
*****************************************************************************"""

intro()

while True:
    print(3*"\n",60*"=")
    print("""MAIN MENU

    1. New Account
    2. Deposit Amount
    3. Withdraw Amount
    4. Balance Enquiry
    5. All Account Holder List
    6. Close An Account
    7. Modify An Account
    8. Exit
    9. Filter Accounts
    """)
```

The code gives an indentation error right after the last triple quote. I can't figure out why, but the error goes away if I remove the "try" clause. Why is this happening ?

Edit : I have edited in the next part of the code, where I call in the main function

Comment: Do `def search():` and `try:` have the same level of indentation in your real code, or is that a transcription error due to Stack Overflow's markup engine?

Comment: I don't get the error where you say. I get it right on the `try:`, which makes sense, because it must be indented under the `def search():`.

Comment: What's in the line after the last triple quote, is there more code?

Comment: @Kevin It is a transcription error. The "try" and "except" statements are properly indented in my file.

Comment: @Dan Yes, there is more code, but I don't know how to link it all here.

Comment: Well if the error is after the last triple quote, then it's probably with the next line which you haven't shown us... (assuming that you just made a typo in your question about not indenting `try`)

Comment: If I correct the `try` and `except` indentation, I get no error at all. The problem must be with code you haven't posted.

Comment: @FredLarson I'll edit in the ensuing code as well.

Comment: The actual traceback would be helpful too.

Comment: Now I just get, `NameError: name 'intro' is not defined`. No IndentationError.

Answer (score 0):

In python, after every ":" and newline, there needs to be an indentation of atleast one space or tab character.

In your above program, you have declared a function `search()`, and have a semi-colon after it, so in the next line, you need to indent the statements inside the function.

So, you will have to indent `try:` and `except:` statements, and recursively keep indenting the code blocks present in the try/except clauses

Answer (score 0):

I can see two critical section in regards of indentation:

1. `try:` and `except EOFError:` have the same indentaion as `def search():`
2. Your `print` statements are indented by 8 spaces

Comment: Why would the indentation of the print statements be an issue? Indentation must be consistent within a block, but not between different blocks.

Comment: It's not producing an error, but it's making it less readable. It's just inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

maybe here is a problem :

```
def search():
try:
```

try this:

```
def search():
    try:
```

do def search() and try: have same level of  indentation?